# Having trouble understanding cmpsb in the following example

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am following a tutorial on operating systems and I came across the following block code which is checking filenames on a disk against my variable "ImageName".

My confusion arises from the `push di` line before `rep cmpsb`.

```
    mov       cx, WORD [bpbRootEntries]
    mov       di, 0x0200
.LOOP:
    push      cx
    mov       cx, 0x000B
    mov       si, ImageName
    push      di
    rep  cmpsb
    pop       di
    je        LOAD_FAT
    pop       cx
    add       di, 0x0020
    loop      .LOOP
    jmp       FAILURE
```

The documentation I have found for `cmpsb` states "For legacy mode, compare byte at address DS:(E)SI with byte at address ES:(E)DI. The status flags are set accordingly." Wouldn't pushing `di` before this call mean that I am always comparing against an empty value? The code works so I am obviously misunderstanding something, but every piece of documentation I can find implies that this code shouldn't work.

Comment: `push di` has no effect on `di`.

Comment: OOOOOH, ive been operating under that assumption for way to long haha, clears up all my confusion, thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest single-stepping it in a debugger (e.g. BOCHS) to find out where your assumptions are wrong.  IDK why you think saving/restoring DI with push/pop would leave it "empty", but that's not what push does.  Registers can't be "empty", they always have some value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rep cmpsb` instruction will leave `di` pointing after the location where the two strings differ.  Since this code does not care about that position (just if the two strings match), we throw out where the difference lies and just check the Z flag to see if we matched.  If we don't match, we advance `di` far enough to get to the next file name, which is a constant since we reset `di` back to where we started.

Comment: aren't i comparing si to di though? does pushing a register not clear its value?

Comment: @ouchqt Pushing a register just copies its value to the stack to preserve it, so it can be restored later with a `pop`.

Comment: ahh, i'm not sure where i got that from then but thank you! a lot of things ive seen just started making sense haha

Comment: Most programmers would prefer to see `REPE CMPSB`. Better distinction from `REPNE CMPSB`.